# I am getting Problem in python list how to solve

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

```
usernames = ["Trinity Ball","Arely Strong"  ]

username1 = usernames[1]

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher?next=%2Faccount&feature=settings")

sleep(18)

switch = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//yt-formatted-string[contains(text(), 'username1')]")
switch.click()
```

please help I stuck here for 2 days. it is saying Message:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//yt-formatted-string[contains(text(), 'username1')]"}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: sir i am trying to click on youtube channel id collected from list

Comment: please help sir if you want to ask something more i am here to tell you thanks in advance

Comment: did you logged in to the youtube before running the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the below **error**

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//yt-formatted-string[contains(text(), 'username1')]"}

It is clear that the variable you are passing to the `xpath` it is treating as a string not argument.

Use python `format()` function to pass the variable.

```
switch = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//yt-formatted-string[contains(text(), '{}')]".format(username1))
switch.click()
```